# jQuery - Prefix value to CSS Class dynamically based on other id

Tags: jquery

**I am new to jQuery**

I want to prefix other element ID for existing CSS class...

### Explanation:

**I have a table like below:**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="xyz">Student 1</td>
            <td class="student-name">Mark</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="abc">Student 3</td>
            <td class="student-name">Mitchelle</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Eg: I have two TDs with Student Number and Name.
I want to prefix same id "**xyz**" from first TD to the **Mark** TD CSS class, **abc** to **Johnson**'s TD etc... dynamically.

**Please check this**

```
<td class="student-name">Mark</td>
<td class="student-name">Johnson</td>
```

Should changed to

```
<td class="xyz-student-name">Mark</td>
<td class="abc-student-name">Johnson</td>
```

Can somebody please help me out?

### [Please Check this Fiddle for the Same](http://jsfiddle.net/j0s7qs5p/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by matching all of the `.student-name` elements and then looping them with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and, if they have a previous sibling ([`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev)) with an `id`, update the class. Something like this:

```
$(".student-name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.prev().attr("id");
    if (id) {
        $this.removeClass("student-name").addClass(id + "-student-name");
    }
});
```

If there isn't any previous sibling, `$this.prev()` will return an empty jQuery set. If you call `.attr("id")` on an empty jQuery set, you get back `undefined`; if there's an element in the set, though, you'll get back the `id` of the first element, which might be `""`. So then we use `if (id)` because we want to do this if `id` is *truthy**. Then it's a simple matter of removing the old class and adding the new one.

---

* "truthy" - Values are *truthy* if they're not *falsey*. The falsey values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`.

---

Side note: You may not need to do this with JavaScript at all, depending on why you're changing that class name. If the goal is to style the elements differently, and you don't need to support old browsers, you can do it with CSS using an [*adjacent sibling combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`):

```css
#abc + student-name {
    /* Styles for abc-student-name */
}
#def + student-name {
    /* Styles for def-student-name */
}
```

Comment: Awesome.....

Thanks Crowder... You saved my JOB :)

Between... many thanks to StackOverflow for the excellent work... Keep up the good work Guys

Comment: Thanks again @Crowder... Need one more help... Please check the New Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j0s7qs5p/4/) ... How can I replace the same CSS class with TD Value? Please suggest... **Eg:** css class **student-name** of Mark has to be changed to **MK123-student-name**

Comment: Sorry Crowder.. After seeing your answer, I have clicked on Vote Up... But I can't vote up for your great work now, because of my reputation score :(

Comment: @Reddy: You'll be able to upvote when you have a rep >= 15, don't worry. Meanwhile, you *can* accept the answer (**if** it answered your question).

Comment: @Reddy: *"Eg: css class student-name of Mark has to be changed to MK123-student-name"* That's exactly lthe same as the above, just put `"MK" +` in front of `id` when adding the class.

Comment: @Crowder, As soon as I get the reputations, I will vote... But these IDs are generating dynamically as a unique number :( ... Eg: For Mark it will be **MK123**, For Johnson it is **JH567**.. Can you please check the Fiddle please? [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/j0s7qs5p/5/)

Comment: @Reddy: So that's a different situation than your question states. You want to grab the *text* of the previous cell. So instead of `id = $this.prev().attr("id")` you want `$this.prev().text()`. Well worth spending some time reading http://api.jquery.com.

Comment: @Reddy: Don't worry about coming back to vote when you get the rep, it's not important enough to bother. Accepting answers that answer your question is important, and again does not require any particular rep.

Comment: @Crowder... Thanks for the suggestion and Hats-Of to your Attitude... :)